# discarding a fragment without defining gl_FragColor triggers warning in browser

Tags: glsl, webgl

With the following fragment shader:

```
void main() {
    discard;
}
```

Chrome (110.0.5481.177) emits a warning:

```
[.WebGL-0x128c003e8d00] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Active draw buffers with missing fragment shader outputs.
```

It can easily be fixed this way:

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0);
    discard;
}
```

But why ? The GLSL specs says about the `discard` keyword:

> The `discard` keyword is only allowed within fragment shaders. It can be used within a fragment shader to
> abandon the operation on the current fragment. This keyword causes the fragment to be discarded and no
> updates to any buffers will occur. Control flow exits the shader [...]

If "control flow exits the shader" and "no updates to any buffers will occur", why should I have to assign any value to `gl_FragColor` prior to `discard` ?

Comment: I *think* this error is only caused because you're guaranteed to never writing anything to the draw buffer in which case you could either not have any draw buffer attached or should disable the color write using `colorMask`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, when I put the `discard` keyword in a conditional branch, the warning disappears.